# Abstract Class with Abstract Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having an issue when using an abstract class with abstract generics.

I can instantiate the subclass, but I can't then refer to it as the abstract supertype.

For example:

```
AbstractInstance<AbstractType> instance = new SubInstance()
```

Where

```
SubInstance extends AbstractInstance(SubType)
```

Gives me "cannot convert from SubInstance to AbstractInstance".

What am I doing wrong?
Proper example included below.

```
public class Demo
{
/**
 * Abstract Instance
 *
 * @param <Type>
 */
public abstract class AbstractInstance<Type extends AbstractType>
{

}

/**
 * Abstract Generic Type
 *
 */
public abstract class AbstractType
{

}

/**
 * Sub Instance that extends AbstractInstance
 *
 */
public class SubInstance extends AbstractInstance<SubType>
{

}

/**
 * SubType that extends AbstractType
 *
 */
public class SubType extends AbstractType
{

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Demo.SubInstance to Demo.AbstractInstance<Demo.AbstractType>
    AbstractInstance<AbstractType> abstractInstance = new SubInstance();

}
}
```

Comment: `SubInstance` is defined to inherit from `AbstractInstance<SubType>`,
so you can´t assign it to `AbstractInstance<AbstractType>`, because `SubInstance` is defined to be a `AbstractInstance` with the generic `SubInstance`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the new part to

```
AbstractInstance<? extends AbstractType> abstractInstance = new SubInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can´t do this, because `SubInstance` is inheriting from `AbstractInstance<SubType>`. Due to this you defined, that `SubType` is a `AbstractInstance` with the generic of `SubType` or any subclass of `SubType`.

But the variable `AbstractInstance<AbstractType> abstractInstance` doesn´t fullfill this condition.

Why? because not every `AbstractType` is a subclass of `SubType`. If you change the variable to be `AbstractInstance<SubType> abstractInstance` your programm will be compiling again

Comment: Well the above is a small example, but I actually want a list:
List<AbstractInstance<AbstractType> list,

and then have multiple subclasses, for example "subInstance1<SubType1>" and "subInstance2<SubType2>" added to this list. So I really need to be able to have AbstractInstance<AbstractType> or similar to be able to do this.